# With Bluetooth turned off in PC settings, do keyboards and mice still emit radiation?

Tags: bluetooth, radiation

Do you know if a wireless mouse emits radiation in wired mode? Using the USB cable, With Bluetooth turned off, but with the switch set to "On"?

And also do you know if a wireless keyboard, also with Bluetooth turned off, emits radiation? Or just uses the radiation that already is available for the PC to be connected with wireless?

Thanks!

Comment: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - this basically means that unless we have very specific design details of the actual mouse you are talking about, then it can't be answered with any level of certainty. The only answer is this: all powered electronic devices are likely to emit some form of radiation at some level. In fact anything above absolute zero emits radiation.

Comment: Thanks! So a wired mouse is also an eletronic device right? So it also emits radiation?

Comment: Any piece of matter above absolute zero emits radiation.

Comment: Wired mice are low BW.

Comment: Thanks, but for example if you already have a router emitting radiation for the computer to have wireless if you then also use a wireless keyboard and wireless mouse  you have additional radiation for using the wireless and keyboard mouse? Or for the keyboard and mice just use the radiation that is already being emitted by the router for the PC connect using wireless?

Comment: Do you mean any radiation, or radiation in the 2.4 GHz Bluetooth band?

Comment: I mean, there is a lot of speculation or evidence, dont really know, that specially for kids the radiation can be negative. I dont have technical background my doubt is that if the route is already emitting radiation for the PC to have connection, there is any additional negative effect to use a wireless mouse  and wireless keyboard? Or the wireless and mouse keyboard are just using the available waves and radiation that already exist because the router is emitting the wireless? (With blueetooth off in PC settings)

Comment: Cellphone power is much higher than Bluetooth (designed for short range). If you are worried about electromagnetic radiation, the first thing to do is keep your kids away from cellphones.

Comment: If your question is really about health risks of Bluetooth radiation then that should be the question you asked. If we tell you that Bluetooth is still on how will that help you with your real question? You can [edit] your question to improve it but do a search for the question first as it has been asked many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this kind of thing you need to define "radiation". We're going to discuss radio frequency electromagnetic interference. (RF EMI) For product testing categories, this is usually divided into

- intentional emission
- unintentional emission
- low-frequency

Everything which works by radio will be an intentional emitter. Wifi, bluetooth, wireless keyboards, etc. These are usually in a narrow band and at a very limited power level. The most powerful one you'll encounter in a normal home is a cellphone; these used to be powerful enough to bleed into your hifi ([Why does GSM cause speakers to buzz?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32830/why-does-gsm-cause-speakers-to-buzz)).

Beyond that, every bit of digital electronics is an unintentional emitter .. at *very* low power levels. Testing for this is part of CE certification. Devices which emit enough RF to interfere with radios are not permitted.

Below about 250kHz is not considered as part of this testing. Anyone in a building wired for mains electricity will be subject to a 50Hz field, and this can be quite easily picked up.

There's no evidence that any of this is harmful. The only thing which is subject to harm testing is the amount of radio energy absorbed by the head of somebody talking on a cellphone; this is covered by the EU "SAR" limits.